# Exportar todas las filas a excel en un datatable

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hola tengo un datatable del cual quiero exportar todas las filas a excel,porque solamente me esta exportando la filas de la pagina actual del datatable, este datatable tiene la propiedad server-side activada pq el gran cumulo de filas que tiene mi tabla,trato mediante un metodo de cambiar el comportamiento del boton excel que trae por defecto datatable pero no logro resultado alguno.

```
let dt = $('#new-cons').DataTable({
            'serverSide': true,
            'processing': true,
            "pageLength": 1000,
            'ajax': {
                    'url': url,
                    'data': function ( d ) {
                                    d.user_id = $('#user-name').val(),
                                    d.bookingId = $('#bookingId').val(),
                                    d.rest_name = $('#rest-name').val(),
                                    d.operator_total_cost = $('#operator-total-cost').val(),
                                    d.total_cost = $('#total-cost').val(),
                                    d.order_area = $('#order-area').val(),
                                    d.order_date = $('#order-date').val()       
                                    d.order_status = $('#order-status').val()                               
                                }
                            },
            'columns': [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                { data: "user_name" },
                { data: "area" },
                { data: store_details },
                { data: "order_no" },
                { data: "created_at" },
                { data: "total_pay" , class: "currency"},
                { data: "status", class: "order-status" },
                { data: "action", class: "order-status" },
            ],
            bLengthChange: false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',        

                buttons: [
                    {
                    text:       'Export CSV',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    
                        $.ajax({
                            "url": url,
                            "data": dt.ajax.params(),
                            "success": function(res, status, xhr) {
                                var csvData = new Blob([res], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
                               
                                var csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
                               
                                var tempLink = document.createElement('a');
                                tempLink.href = csvURL;
                                tempLink.setAttribute('download', 'export.csv');
                                tempLink.click();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }                               
                         
                }
            ],
        });
```